# Printing student records: I want to show every record on a different page

Tags: c#

```
int b = 1;

    //Here is my print document event
    private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (b <= 1)
            {
                //Here im using string connection and fetching data through loop
                conn = new SqlConnection(Db_Path.path);
                conn.Open();
                query = "select StudentsRecord.Student_Id,StudentsRecord.GR_No,StudentsRecord.Section,StudentsRecord.Name,StudentsRecord.Father_Name,Classes.Monthly_Fee,StudentsRecord.Tuition_Fee_Discount from StudentsRecord inner join Classes on StudentsRecord.Admission_Class_Id=Classes.Class_Id where Classes.Class_Name='" + cbclass.SelectedItem + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(dr[5].ToString()) - Convert.ToInt32(dr[6].ToString());
                    int c = a + Convert.ToInt32(txtlatefee.Text);


                    e.Graphics.DrawString("BABA FOUNDATION PUBLIC", new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 10));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("HIGH SCHOOL (REGD)", new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 35));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Domonwah Road Hyderabad.", new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(80, 60));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("School's Copy", new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 90));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Issue Date", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(40, 140));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + txtissuedate.Text, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, 140));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Due Date", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(40, 155));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + txtduedate.Text, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(120, 155));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("V. No.", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 205));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("SID.", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(215, 205));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + dr[0].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(245, 205));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Fee for the month of:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 225));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + txtfeemonth.Text, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 225));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Roll No:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 245));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("GR#:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, 245));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + dr[1].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(220, 245));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Class:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 265));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + cbclass.SelectedItem, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(100, 265));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Sec:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, 265));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + dr[2].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(220, 265));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Name:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 285));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + dr[3].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(70, 285));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("F/Name:", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 305));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + dr[4].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(80, 305));
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 340, 300, 350);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Particulars", new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(65, 345));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Amount", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 345));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 230, 340, 230, 688);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Admission Fee", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 388));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 388));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 380, 320, 380);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Monthly Tuition Fee", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 418));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + a.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 418));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 410, 320, 410);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Other Fee", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 443));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 443));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 440, 320, 440);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Exam Fee", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 470));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 470));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 465, 320, 465);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Stationary Charges", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 494));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 494));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 490, 320, 490);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Annual Charges", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 518));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 518));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 515, 320, 515);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Course Payment", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 545));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 545));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 540, 320, 540);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Library Fee", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 570));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 570));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 565, 320, 565);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Others", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 596));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 596));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 590, 320, 590);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Arrears", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 621));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("0.00", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 621));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 615, 320, 615);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Payable within due date", new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 643));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + a.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 646));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 640, 320, 640);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Payable after due date", new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 667));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("" + c.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(235, 670));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 665, 320, 665);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Rupees (In Words):", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 705));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 785, 320, 785);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Note:", new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 795));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 20, 820, 70, 820);

                    var r = new Rectangle(20, 825, 300, 100);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(txtnote.Text, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, r);


                    if (dr[0].ToString() != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
                        e.HasMorePages = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.HasMorePages = false;

                    }


                }
                b++;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I want to show 1 student record on one page other record on other how should i show every student record on separate page

Comment: What is "challan"?

Comment: student fees Recipt

Comment: Note that `HasMorePages` signals that the `PrintPage` event should be called again for the next page. It doesn't signal the start of a new page for the current `PrintPage` event.

Comment: i have used debug but as more values comes from database how shoud i move other values to next page and show every record on a separate page

Comment: You need to get the data, store it, call Print, then on every call to PrintPage event you print one and set HasMorePages accordingly if there’s still pages to print

Comment: You need to change the logic of your reads. place the reader outside of the printpage event and in it read and drawstring until the page is full __or__ reader is empty. Then return from the event. It will be called again automatically if HasMorePages is true..

Comment: [Challan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challan) is an official form or other kind of document, piece of paperwork, citation, etc.... used in India and Pakistan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the logic of your reads.

Place the reader **outside** of the `PrintPage` event and **in** it read and `DrawString` etc until the page is full or reader is empty. Then return from the event. **It will be called again automatically** if `HasMorePages` is true..

Here is an example of a print logic structure:

```
SqlDataReader dr = null;
PrintDocument pdoc = null;
int pageNr = 0;

private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // connect and open reader
    // ..
    // set up the print document..
    pdoc = new PrintDocument();
    pdoc.DocumentName = "Printer Test";
    pdoc.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
    // ..
    pageNr = 0;
    pdoc.Print();
    // close connection & reader..
}

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    bool pageDone = false;
    pageNr++;
    if (pageNr > maxPage) return;  // optional

    while(dr.Read())
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;  // we have more data
        // print stuff
        // ..
        // if each Read fills one page..:
        pageDone = true; // ..or else use condition like y > yMax
        if (pageDone) return;  // return to print next page
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro i tried your same method but my loop is going infinite

Comment: That should not happen; the reader should come to an end, right? Make sure to set HasMorePages to true only inside the read loop and after the reader has successfully read a record.. - It works fine here. Did you separate printpage and opening the reader? Can you use the debugger to trace the loop? Can you post the updated code?

Comment: Thank you so much bro i was trying it from 3 days but finally with your help i done it

Comment: Ok bro and again Thank you so much